# Can't get Error message in PHP

Tags: php, include

I have a login Form `index.php` which has input as ID and Password.I get the input and submit it to another File called
`login_user.php`
which accepts the data.

If the Credentials are correct then User is routed to the home Page correctly. But when the user has put wrong login details, I have to check with the stored values in the DB.So what I thought is using some `variable` in `login_user.php` and then `include` it in `index.php` and print the error in the `div`. So far I made this code.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert" id="alert_login_error">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <strong id="error_flag">
            Invalid Login Details
        </strong>
</div>
  <?php
    include "login_user.php";
    if (empty($error)) {
      echo "<script>  $('#alert_login_error').hide(); console.log('empty');</script>";
    }
    else {
      echo "<script>  $('#alert_login_error').show();console.log('not empty');</script>";
    }
 ?>
```

And `login_user.php` file has this

```
$error = ""; #this is set at the start of the file
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($num_rows > 0) {
              #User is redirected to Home Page if details are correct
              #If the password is wrong then in a function
               $error = "Invalid password";
               header('Location: index.php');
            }
            else {
              $error = "Invalid Login details";
              header('Location: index.php');
            }
```

What this code does

> When `index.php` is loaded the `div`in which error is defined is hide. This works fine.
>
> but when user inputs wrong login inputs. then also the `div` is set to hide

I don't understand where I am making mistake.If anything more is needed please ask, so that I can provide.Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're setting `$error` in both cases, so `empty($error)` will never be true.

Comment: You can't call `header()` after printing output. You print the `<div>` before you include `login_user.php`, so those header calls will not do anything.

Comment: @Barmar but I need to redirect to `login.php` page if user inputs are wrong. so I use this `header()`

Comment: I understand that. You just have to reorganize the code so it doesn't print the DIV first.

Comment: @xNeyte If user inputs correct ID but wrong password then I have to say user that wrong password is entered.So I have used this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personnally use $_SESSION variable to manage errors through PHP script.

Your div would be

`<div id='error'> {$_SESSION['error']} </div>`

And you kill it just after you displayed it.

This is heredoc syntax. Sorry if you're not used to it.

In this way, you don't have to manage show/hide div, since the div will be empty if `$_SESSION['error']` is empty

Note : I don't know if this is a good solution, but it is a working solution at least!

So your PHP script would be :

```
 if ($num_rows > 0) {
          #User is redirected to Home Page if details are correct
          #If the password is wrong then in a function
           $_SESSION['error'] = "Invalid password";
           header('Location: index.php');
 }
 else {
          $_SESSION['error'] = "Invalid Login details";
          header('Location: index.php');
 }
```

Comment: Session has helped me. Before Login screen I destroyed all the sessions and that worked fine.. Thank You!!

Comment: The problem with this solution is that every time you hit the page after setting the `$_SESSION['error']` variable would show the same error message. For example, if the user tried to log in, then went to the home page, then went _back_ to the login page, the same error message would should up - obviously a poor user experience. What you should do, if you're going to do it this way, is delete the variable after you display it once by executing `unset($_SESSION['error']);` - then it won't appear on future page views.

Comment: That's why I said him to kill it just after he displayed it! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are immediately redirecting the user using your `header('location: index.php')` code; as soon as this happens, `$error` is wiped clean in the event of a clean page load, which means that your `if (empty($error))` conditional will always evaluate to `true`.

Comment: Sorry but how would I redirect the user back to `index.php` that is login screen.Anything to avoid this?

Comment: You can do one of several things:
1. Execute an Ajax call to determine if the user authenticated correctly
2. Use a `$_SESSION['loginResponse']` variable to display something once, then immediately `unset` the variable after displaying it